# My refresh rate seems to be to slow on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a Windows Phone game. The game is just a simple logical puzzle that does not require a lot of CPU.

I used a timer to update every 16 ms so it will give me a 60 FPS. It's updates very slow!

```
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        mainCanvas.Children.Clear();
        redraw();
    }
```

I have a feeling that there is a flaw in my logic as its not necessary to delete all objects from the screen. However, I am not sure how to delete only one object as its multiple of many shapes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Creating a game using WPF isn't the most amazing idea.  Expecting a phone to guarantee to keep up with a 60Hz refresh isn't reasonable either.  And to top it off, deleting and re-creating all the visuals on a timer is definitely the wrong approach.  You should be looking at more suitable frameworks such as Cocos2Dx http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_Installation_and_Setup   

If you're dead set on using WPF, follow some Microsoft guidelines to start with https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/03/13/how-to-make-a-windows-store-game-with-c-and-xaml-part-1/

Comment: Thank you. How do I install Coco2d so I can use it in my visual studio

Comment: Did you even read the Cocos2D URL that I pointed you to?  That is basically entirely just a description of doing exactly what you just asked.

Comment: Minor point: Windows Phone uses a flavour of Silverlight, not WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exceeding the system capabilities with this complete screen redraw of all objects at 16ms rate!

Change this elapsed time for something like 200ms (5x per second) and you will see a good improvement.

Remember also that different Windows Phone devices may impact in your solution - worst CPU/RAM device will be slower than faster ones.

Good luck